# How to check term ID present in database table before updating

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I need to increment a counter on every taxonomy page load. I am adding the code in **taxonomy-term.tpl.php** file in my theme. I need to add a new entry if the term is not present and need to increment the 'totalview' if its already present. Here is my code, can any one help me to add the condition.

```
db_insert('custom_file_download_count')
->fields(array(
  'totalview' => 1,
  'tid' => arg(2),
  'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'uid' => $GLOBALS['user']->uid,
))

db_update('custom_file_download_count')
->fields(array(
  'totalview' => 1,
  'tid' => arg(2),
  'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'uid' => $GLOBALS['user']->uid,
))
->expression('totalview', 'totalview + 1')
->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compound key you need to check for is for `uid` & `tid`. You can check for a row's existance (thus, need to insert) with a `db_query` function call & `rowCount` method call.

```
if(db_query('SELECT totalview FROM {custom_file_download_count} WHERE tid = :tid AND uid = :uid', array(':tid' => $tid, ':uid' => $GLOBALS['user']->uid))->rowCount() == 0) {
  db_insert('custom_file_download_count')
  ->fields(array(
    'totalview' => 0,
    'tid' => arg(2),
    'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
    'uid' => $GLOBALS['user']->uid,
  ))->execute();
}
db_update('custom_file_download_count')
->fields(array(
  'totalview' => 1,
  'tid' => arg(2),
  'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'uid' => $GLOBALS['user']->uid,
))
->expression('totalview', 'totalview + 1')
->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn...The if condition will check if there is an entry. Do we need to include db_update inside else{}. Because the db_update needs to search for existing entry and increment  totaltime by 1. I need to restrict  duplication of same entry.

Comment: You don't need an else block; the if block gets executed to initialize the row (if it doesn't exist); in either case the update will be executed to update the count (initialization sets the value to 0).

Comment: I tried this code. Its not inserting any new entry. I truncated the table and tried. No new row is inserting.

Comment: I assumed your above code was already working. You forgot to add the `execute()` method to `db_insert()`. It's been fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for you update  Shawn. I tried the code. Both insert and update works fine. But the totalview value for all tids are incrementing on any taxonomy page load. I created two taxonomy pages (term/1 & term/2) and loaded both pages for the first time. Two rows are inserted in table with the details. Again i loaded only term/1, totalview fields in both rows gets incremented.

Comment: Your question only asked about queries need to create the counters. Troubleshooting the issue about when/where to execute the counter should be broken into a separate question to prevent this comment thread from getting too long.

Comment: My requirement is to get the visitor count of taxonomy term pages. If the visit is for first time, need to INSERT the data to database as a new entry. But visit from second time onwards, the existing   totalview needs to increment (UPDATE) by one.The code works as expected, but all the rows in the table is getting updated on every page load. The expected behavior is to update only row related to a term.

Comment: Please stop asking new questions in the comment area. Drupal Answers isn't a forum. The format here is to ask a short answerable questions and add answers to *that question*. If you have a new question about `db_query` & Oracle, ask it as a new question.

Comment: Shawn Conn...Update condition is triggering once i updated `->rowCount()` to `->fetchField()`  . But update fails.